# Accessing the model in donejs view when passing the parameter from child to parent

Tags: donejs

From official documentation : 
[passing model from donejs Child component to Parent component model](https://v2.canjs.com/docs/can.view.bindings.toParent.html#section_ExportingViewModelproperties)

I have included search filter component in my homepage component and another product table component which is to be updated when the filters change.

HomePage Comp(stache file) :

```
<can-import from="../searchFilter">
  <searchfilter {^filter-list}="*filters" />
</can-import>
```

How to access this "*filters" in the homepage component js file?
I have already tried : since * filters is an array, if i pass it as a custom data attribute, it becomes "[object][object]".

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to access the "*filters" property here was to send the property on the change of the component :

```
<can-import from="../status-searchFilter/" ($change)="update(*filters)">
    <status-searchfilter {^filter-List}="*filters"/>
</can-import>
```